# References do not appear using TexStudio and MiKTex

Tags: bibtex, miktex, texstudio

I reinstalled the `TexStudio` and `MiKTex` recently. When I want to generate my document, my biblography (references) does not appear and I always get the following error. I went through the similar questions, but I could not solve the problem yet.
Also, I already checked the `configure Texstudio->command->bibtex`, and the address that is there is `"C:/Program Files/MikTex/miktex/bin/x64/bibtex.exe" %`

**The error is:**

```
Error: Could not start the command: "C:/Program Files/MikTex/miktex/bin/x64/bibtex.exe" "main"

Process started: "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "main".tex

Process exited normally
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The configuration should be `C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/bibtex.exe` You can set it via the Configure TeX Studio interface.

Comment: @Bernard Do you want to write down an answer or do we have a duplicate for this?

Comment: @moewe: I have no idea whether this is a duplicate. As this kind of problems happen mainly with beginners, and I'm not sure there's an *exact* duplicate, I'll write a short answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally (if you install TeXStudio *after* MiKTeX), all executables should be in the PATH, and TeX Studio should find them.

In your case you can  load the configuration interface of TeX Studio (menu `Options -> Configure TeX Studio`, `Commands` tab. Click  on the small blue icon on the right of the `bibtex` field to indicate  where it should find it, like in this screenshot:

[image]